# What's the usage of assignment operator after the fat arrow operator in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having trouble understanding the method below

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

In my understanding of the arrow function

```
heroes => this.heroes
```

is basically,

```
function(heroes){
  return this.heroes;
}
```

But what's the equal to after this.heroes doing?

```
this.heroes = heroes
```

Isn't this.heroes supposed to be the return value? How can you assign something to return value?

Docs on Angular page just says subscribe () emmits the the array to callback which sets the component's heroes property. This isn't very clear to me.

So, if anyone could help explain what's happening inside of subscribe() method or rewrite the arrow function in normal function, would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of your question, `this.heroes = heroes` is the body of the function.

```js
heroes => this.heroes = heroes
```

is equivalent to writing

```js
function setHeroes(heroes) {
  this.hereos = heroes;
}
```

One big difference is in Javascript function, `this` keyword denotes the scope of the function. So `this.hereos = heroes` isn't assigning the value to the member variable (`heroes` property) as per the intention. This is because Javascript has no concept of classes.

In the arrow function, `this` denotes the scope of the current class. So when you say `this.heroes = heroes`, the value emitted by the source observable is assigned to the member variable property `heroes`.

One easy way to understand is to build the code and search the `main.bundle.js` file for the function `getHeroes()`. It will give a good idea of how it is compiled into Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
heroes => this.heroes = heroes
```

is equivalent to :

```
heroes => { 
  this.heroes = heroes;
}
```

which means it will execute the code after the fat arrow.

"each time the observable emits, assign to the field `this.heroes` the value emittted"

Like usual functions, arrow functions can also just execute codewithout returning anything explicitly. (We say that you want to execute the function for its *side effect*).

Technically, it's the same thing with the return. It's just that, here, the return value of the `subscribe` callback is completely ignored.

`return this.heroes = heroes;` is actually executed. But the return value is ignored, so it would be weird if explicitly written. The assignment in the return is a side-effect, which is actually all the important part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
getHeroes() {
  this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

`this.heroService.getHeroes()` is being subscribed, meaning when this gets a result it will be assigned to the local instance `this.heroes`.

You can call it whatever you want, for example this will also work:

```
this.heroService.getHeroes().subscribe(result => this.heroes = result);
```

Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `heroes => this.heroes = heroes` is equivalent to

```
heroes => {
  return (this.heroes = heroes);
}
```

Basically `this.heroes = heroes` returns the value of the right-hand side of the expression. So to be more detailed it means:

```
heroes => {
  this.heroes = heroes;
  return heroes;
}
```

You have passed the arrow function to the `.subscribe` method which disregards the returning value of the arrow function, so it is totally valid to write that way.